# Can't float element to left because the order is in below

Tags: css, css-float

```
<ul class="unlist clearfix">
            <li class="clearfix">
                <h3>List Item</h3>
                <time datetime="2013-08-29"><span>29</span> Ags 2013</time>
            </li>
            <li class="clearfix">
                <h3>List Item</h3>
                <time datetime="2013-08-29"><span>29</span> Ags 2013</time>
            </li>
            <li class="clearfix">
                <h3>List Item</h3>
                <time datetime="2013-08-29"><span>29</span> Ags 2013</time>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Currently it shows something like this

- List Item

  29 Ags 2013
- List Item

  29 Ags 2013
- List Item

  29 Ags 2013

I want to float the `29 Ags 2013`, using `float:left;`. So it appears like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rwVIvQQ.png]

But nothing happens. I tried setting `<time>` to `display:block;` but still nothing happens.

Found out that it would float left IF I change the order to:

```
<li class="clearfix">
            <time datetime="2013-08-29"><span>29</span> Ags 2013</time>
            <h3>List Item</h3>
</li>
```

But I don't want that. I want the `<time>` below `<h3>`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
h3,time{
    display: inline; //or inline-block
}
time{
    float: left;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U6DZH/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, best and simple solution! Really forgot `inline-block`